# Android dialog has no padding

Tags: android, dialog

I have a problem with AlertDialog - dialog has no padding (like on screenshot - dialog with no padding inside).

[image]

My Activity has theme  "NoActionBar"

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

My Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDial();
        }
    });
}

private void showDial() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Delete entry")
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
            .setPositiveButton("tak", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // continue with delete
                }
            })
            .show();
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You must use custom view in your dialog alert

```
private void showDial() {

    View content = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_alert, null);
    ((TextView)content.findViewById(R.id.dialogTitle)).setText("Delete entry");
    ((TextView)content.findViewById(R.id.dialogText)).setText("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?");


    AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Test.this, R.style.no_title_dialog)
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setPositiveButton("tak", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // continue with delete
                }
            })
            .setView(content)
            .create();
    alert.show();
}
```

custom_dialog_alert.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialogTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:lines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="26dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:text="Dialog title"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialogText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:maxHeight="300dp"
            android:text="Dialog text"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

no_title_dialog in styles.xml

```
<style name="no_title_dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Add this style to your dialog.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(StartUpActivity.this
                ,R.style.AlertDialogCustom));


<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">false</item>
    </style>
```